# Variable to generate previous data in ssis Package?

Tags: t-sql, ssis, ftp, sql-server-2012, expression

I have created a variable which will checks present date how can i get previous date using below expression?

```
"/Report-"+(DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(GETDATE())
+ RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR, 2) MONTH(GETDATE()) ,2)
+ RIGHT("0"+(DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(GETDATE()) ,2)+ ".csv"

Result:
/Report-20140210.csv
```

How can i get if i need previous date

```
/Report-20140209.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to apply the dateadd expression to GetDate indicating that you wish to subtract one day.

```
"/Report-" + 
(DT_WSTR, 4)  YEAR(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())) 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)  MONTH(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())), 2) 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())), 2)
+ ".csv"
```

Yields `/Report-20140209.csv`

Comment: @bilinkc:Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
"/Report-" + 
(DT_WSTR, 4)  YEAR(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())) 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2)  MONTH(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())), 2) 
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(dateadd("d", -1, getdate())), 2)
+ ".csv
```